# "SOLVED" object after be created with firstOrCreate have 0 as Id in php and right id in DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i saving object to DB with firstOrCreate eloquent method.
code:

```
        $card = Card::firstOrCreate(
            [
                'id' => $product->id
            ],
            [
                'foil' => $data->foil,
                'nonfoil' => $data->nonfoil,
                'oversized' => $data->oversized,
                'reserved' => $data->reserved,
                'booster' => $data->booster,
                'scryfallCollectorNumber' => $data->collector_number,
                'fullArt' => $data->full_art,
                'promo' => $data->promo,
                'story_spotlight' => $data->story_spotlight,
                'textless' => $data->textless,
            ]);
        \Debugbar::info($card->id);
```

in DB is for example 10258 but in debugbar is 0

Comment: what about `dd($card->id);` ?

Comment: Because maybe record with that id exists, but can not update, maybe your date failed validation, that is a reason why $card is 0(false), please try execute that query with SQL I think you should get the error, about dd is the same result @ChristopheHubert

Comment: Can you show us the Model and migration code? Maybe related with https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27727 or https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22388

Comment: @VaheGalstyan I believe the `firstOrCreate` should always return an `$card` and can't return 0/false/null. If the record wasn't created then you would get a `trying to get property id from a non object` error when calling `$card->id`

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED]

3. thank you [porloscerros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7498116/porloscerros-%ce%a8).

That was the problem. I didnt set incrementing to false in model.

`public $incrementing = false;`

1. `dd($card->id);` gives 0 too.

2., 4. that happend only whew new row was created.
with right Id in DB and object was returned with 0 Id.