# Occasionally Laravel firstOrCreate results in 0 id value and results in Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

Job file

```
/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    try {
        $address = $this->setupCustomer();

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        throw $exception;
    }
}

protected function setupCustomer(): CustomerAddress
{
    $customer = Customer::firstOrCreate(
        [
            'email' => $this->transactionDetails['email'],  
        ],
        [
            'first_name' => $this->transactionDetails['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $this->transactionDetails['last_name'],
            'phone' => $this->transactionDetails['phone'] ?? '',
        ]
    );

    return $customer->addAddress([
        'street_address' => $this->transactionDetails['delivery_address']['address'],
        'street_address2' => $this->transactionDetails['delivery_address']['address2'],
        'postal_code' => $this->transactionDetails['delivery_address']['post_code'],
        'city' => $this->transactionDetails['delivery_address']['city'],
        'region' => $this->transactionDetails['delivery_address']['region'],
        'country' => $this->transactionDetails['delivery_address']['country'],
    ]);

}
```

Customer.php Model

```
public function addAddress(array $address): CustomerAddress
{
    $countryId = optional(Country::byCountryCode($address['country'])
        ->first())
        ->id;

    $address = $this->addresses()->firstOrCreate([
        'country_id' => $countryId ?? 0,
        'street_address' => $address['street_address'],
        'street_address2' => $address['street_address2'] ?? null,
        'post_code' => $address['postal_code'],
        'city' => $address['city'],
        'region' => $address['region'],
    ]);

    return $address;
}

/**
 * Customer can have many addresses.
 *
 * @return HasMany
 */
public function addresses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CustomerAddress::class);
}
```

Occasionally, I get the error below:

`` SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tbps`.`customer_addresses`, CONSTRAINT `customer_addresses_customer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `customer_addresses` (`country_id`, `street_address`, `street_address2`, `post_code`, `city`, `region`, `customer_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (<country_id>, <street_address>, ?, <post_code>, <city>, ?, 0, <timestamp>, <timestamp>)) ``

Why does it end up with the customer_id = 0 in the SQL statement? The customer is always created in the database--I am unable to replicate as it occurs occasionally.

Object from Stripe

```
{
    "payment_id": "pi_3MRiqNE7F1cRlWVXXXXXXXXX",
    "currency": "gbp",
    "payment_type": "card",
    "email": "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com",
    "name": null,
    "first_name": "XXXXX",
    "last_name": "XXXX",
    "phone": "07XXXXXXXXX",
    "purchase_dt": "2023/XX/XX XX:XX:XX",
    "discount_code": null,
    "delivery_address": {
        "address": "<address>",
        "address2": null,
        "city": "<city>",
        "post_code": "<post_code>",
        "region": null,
        "country": "<country>"
    },
...
...
}
```

Comment: @Win i think it's even weirder then that. I think he has some customers in DB that have non numerical id values.

Comment: @N69S if the customer_id is string ...  then this problem is already solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61415134/solved-object-after-be-created-with-firstorcreate-have-0-as-id-in-php-and-righ  ... by adding `public $incrementing = false` inside model Customer.

Comment: @Win No, its not solved. It works fine in local system when tested, it works fine on live system most of the time. 1 in 30 orders face this issue.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia those errors,  are they only happened when `create new user` or also when `existing user` ? and what is your `phone` field type , string right ?

Comment: @Win Only for new users it happens, but not for all new users.. 1 in 25 users experience this issue.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia I recommend you use `if ($customer->wasRecentlyCreated )`  and within it log the `$this->transactionDetails` and `$customer` , make sure you understand why this error happen, also improve your customer data validation , especially on all inputs that are required in `table customers` , OR use ->nullable() in migration ... because I suspect your customer inputs data from transactionDetails were not validated properly (empty)

Answer (score 1):

I am having this issue too! This is how we have it set up:

```
class ModelOne
{
    public function modelTwo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ModelTwo::class);
    }
}

class ModelTwo
{
    public function modelOnes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ModelOne::class);
    }
}

$modelOne = ModelOne::findOrFail(1);

$modelTwo = ModelTwo::firstOrCreate([
        'tenant_id' => 1,
        'machine_name' = 'my_new_model_1',
    ], [
        'name' => 'My new model',
    ]);

$modelOne->modelTwo()->associate($modelTwo);
```

Then I randomly get:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`model_one`, CONSTRAINT `model_one_model_two_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`model_two_id`) REFERENCES `model_two` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL) (SQL: update `model_one` set `model_two_id` = 0, `model_one`.`updated_at` = ? where `id` = ?)
```

But I cant reproduce it locally, I just get emails from customers asking to fix it...